# How nested for loop that has complexity O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, for-loop

Given:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n;  i *= 2) {
  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    // Statement(s) that take(s) constant time
  }
}
```

Running Time Complexity = `O(n)`

Explanation was:
[image]

I understand that the outer loop is `log(n)` and the inner loop is `O(n)`.
But why time complexity is not `O(n log n)`? why it's `O(n + log n)`?

Comment: When they compute that the inner loop runs 2n-1 they don't mean for each cycle of the outer loop. They computed the total number of runs of the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

The partial sums calculation is correct. However, the total execution time explanation is unclear, although the result is indeed `O(n)`.
The actual time is consumed by executing the inner statements and the number of these statements executions is defined by the loops. The method of partial sums already takes into consideration **both loops** (1 time unit for i=1, 2 time units for i=2, 4 time units for i=4, etc.) and in total the internal statements are executed `O(n)` times as shown by the partial sums calculation. Therefore, total time is `O(n)*O(constant for the internal statements)=O(n)`. I don't see any reason to include the `O(logn)` in calculations here.

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop runs `log(n)` times. But, in each time, the inner loop does not run in `O(n)`. As shown in the explanation, if `i = 1`, the inner loop runs `1` time. If `i = 2`, the inner loop runs 2 times. If `i = 4`, the inner loop runs `4` times. Hence, the total number of running time is `T(n) = 1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^log(n)`.

Now, simplify the `T(n)`:

```
T(n) = 2^(log(n)+1) - 1 = 2^log(n) * 2 - 1 = 2n - 1 = Theta(n)
```